# How to use multiple colours in a single vertical line of a table?

Tags: tables, color

I have this table, based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519031/hhline-vertical-line-color-changes):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}


\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
   &  & \\ \hline
   &  & \\ 
    \hhline{
      >{\arrayrulecolor{yellow}} | 
      >{\arrayrulecolor{black}}  -
      >{\arrayrulecolor{yellow}} |
      >{\arrayrulecolor{black}}  -
      >{\arrayrulecolor{yellow}} |
      >{\arrayrulecolor{black}}  -
      >{\arrayrulecolor{yellow}} |
      >{\arrayrulecolor{black}} 
    }
   &  & \\
    \hhline{
      >{\arrayrulecolor{yellow}} | 
      >{\arrayrulecolor{black}}  -
      >{\arrayrulecolor{yellow}} |
      >{\arrayrulecolor{black}}  -
      >{\arrayrulecolor{yellow}} |
      >{\arrayrulecolor{black}}  -
      >{\arrayrulecolor{yellow}} |
      >{\arrayrulecolor{black}} 
    }
   &  & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want the vertical lines in the third row to be yellow.

I have read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40666/how-to-change-line-color-in-tabular), but the colour affects to all the rows.

Comment: See `tabularray`, some interesting examples are on pages  10,  12 in package documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Example solution based on @Zarko comment:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
vlines = {1,3,5}{red},
vlines = {2,4}{blue},
}
Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Delta \\
Epsilon & Zeta & Eta & Theta \\
Iota & Kappa & Lambda & Mu \\
Nu & Xi & Omicron & Pi \\
Rho & Sigma & Tau & Upsilon \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

As I mentioned in the my comment, this can be relative simple done by use of `tabularray` package (I use version 2022C):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {*{3}{Q[c]}},
             hline{2-Y} = {even}{black},
             hline{2-Y} = {odd}{yellow,leftpos = 0, rightpos = 0},
             hline{1,Z} = {black},
             vlines,
             }
    &   &   \\
    &   &   \\
    &   &   \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

or this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {*{3}{Q[c]}},
             hline{2-Y} = {even}{black},
             hline{2-Y} = {odd}{yellow,leftpos = 0, rightpos = 0},
             hline{1,Z} = {black},
             vline{1,2,4} = {black}, vline{3} = {yellow},
             }
    &   &   \\
    &   &   \\
    &   &   \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

`{NiceTabular}` of the package `nicematrix` behaves as the classical environment {tabular} (of `array`) but creates also PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, columns and rows. You can use Tikz do draw whatever rule you want with any Tikz style of line.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[hvlines]
& & & \\
& & & \\
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} [line width = 1pt]
  \draw [red] (1-|1) -- (1-|2) (1-|3) -- (1-|4) ; 
  \draw [white] (2-|2) -- (2-|5) ;
  \draw [densely dash dot] (2-|2) -- (2-|5) ;
  \draw [blue,double] (1-|2) -- (3-|2) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]